# Creating images that can use as buttons in html

Tags: html, forms, image, input

I am creating a site in html, and in a part of it, the user need to click on different images.
But I don't know how can I get input from the user clicking on the image like on checkboxes.
 So how can I do that as part of a form so when they submit, I know which images they chose
Thank you!

Comment: use se images as lables for invisible checkboxes

Comment: thank you very much! that's a great idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use invisible checkboxes and set the image inside a label. So if an image is clicken, you will trigger the checkbox

```css
.imageCheck {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.imageCheck:checked + label {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<input class="imageCheck" type="checkbox" id="img1" />
<label for="img1">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</label>

<input class="imageCheck" type="checkbox" id="img2" />
<label for="img2">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</label>

<input class="imageCheck" type="checkbox" id="img3" />
<label for="img3">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks!, that's what Jarlik showed before but now I have a visual example so thank you!

Comment: I try to put margin between the inputs but because of display: none; i can't, so do you have any idea so I can? thanks

Comment: you dont need to add margin to the inputs but to the lables. I have edited my post, have a look at it

Comment: I thought I uploaded it already but I didn't. So thank you very much for all of your help!